# Functions with IF, ELSE "If AVG of total price is higher than price of the game return 0, else return 1"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_unkcija(naziv_igrice IN VARCHAR)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
        rezultat1 NUMBER(1);
        rezultat2 NUMBER(1);
BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(igrice.cijena_ukupno) INTO rezultat1
    FROM igrice;

    SELECT cijena_ukupno INTO rezultat2
    FROM igrice
    IF rezultat1 > rezultat2 THEN
        RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        RETURN 1;
    END IF;
END;
```

I've been trying to solve this with no success, getting errors:

9/5       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

11/8      PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

13/5      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

16/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after `FROM igrice`, and probably some conditions as well.

Comment: missing semi colon after 2nd "FROM igrice". But... this is going to fail. You are using an aggregate function (AVG) in the first SELECT INTO statement. That will return 1 row which is correct. But you will get all rows in the 2nd statement which will result in a too_many_rows exception

Answer (score 0):

You should change your second select query because it will return more than one row and you will have an error message. You can use [CURSOR](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-cursors) for comparing. Try below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_UNKCIJA (NAZIV_IGRICE IN VARCHAR)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   REZULTAT1   NUMBER (1);

   --  rezultat2   NUMBER (1);

   CURSOR CURR
   IS
      SELECT CIJENA_UKUPNO FROM IGRICE;
BEGIN
   SELECT AVG (IGRICE.CIJENA_UKUPNO) INTO REZULTAT1 FROM IGRICE;

   FOR I IN CURR
   LOOP
      IF I.CIJENA_UKUPNO > REZULTAT2
      THEN
         RETURN 0;
      ELSE
         RETURN 1;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```